# Failed to deploy missing security Test

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have successfully gotten the module 41 sample running with eclipse and the local server.  Attempting to deploy on my liberty server returns the error.

Failed to deploy application 'PushApplication-all.wlapp'. : application descriptor uses a security test:PushApplication-strong-mobile-securityTest. However, authentication config xml does not contain a security test element with that name.

I am on Worklight 5.0.5 with a successful app running on the server and now trying to add push notifications.  I have checked the war file and it does contain the authentication-config.xml with the specified test.

I saw a smilier post a few momths ago but am unable to find whether it got answered

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure to replace your current war file (deployed on the liberty server) with the war file belonging to the push notifications project?

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you are trying to deploy your .wlapp to a server that is already running an instance of Worklight, but this instance does not have the required securityTest settings in authenticationConfig.xml

This leads me to believe that you did not replace the .war file you already had deployed in the Liberty-profile application server with the .war file from your Push Notifications project, which contains the up-to-date authenticationConfig.xml